# How to manage COUNT, GROUP BY and HAVING?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, inner-join, having-clause

I'm not experimented in SQL and I try maybe to do something which is impossible. SQL give this sensation it is possible to do it on only 1 request, but maybe not...

I have 4 joined tables A -> S -> T -> F.
A simple request give me these data :

```
select a.id, s.id, t.type, f.name
from table_a a
    inner join table_s s on a.id = s.id
    inner join table_t t on t.id = s.t_id
    inner join table_f f on f.id = t.f_id
where f.name = 'C';

a.id | s.id | t.type | f.name
-----------------------------
1    | 1    | E      | C
1    | 2    | R      | C
2    | 3    | E      | C
3    | 4    | R      | C
```

I would like to find ALL A ids which have multiple S rows associated.
And I would like to find ALL a ids which have only one S row of T type = R.

For the first one, I made this SQL query :

```
select a.id from table_a a
    inner join table_s s on a.id = s.id
    inner join table_t t on t.id = s.t_id
    inner join table_f f on f.id = t.f_id
where f.name = 'C'
group by a.id
having count(s.*) > 1;
```

But now, for the second query I don't understand how to filter on t.type and count.
I try this request but the response is not good (a.id = 1 is returned)

```
select a.id from table_a a
    inner join table_s s on a.id = s.id
    inner join table_t t on t.id = s.t_id
    inner join table_f f on f.id = t.f_id
where f.name = 'C'
group by a.id
having count(s.*) = 1 and t.type = 'R';
```

Any idea ?
Thank you

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to find ALL a ids which have only one S row of T type = R.

Does this do what you want?

```
select a.id from table_a a
    inner join table_s s on a.id = s.id
    inner join table_t t on t.id = s.t_id
    inner join table_f f on f.id = t.f_id
where f.name = 'C' 
group by a.id
having count(*) = 1 and min(t.type) = 'R'
```

This gives you groups that have only one row, whose type is "R".

Comment: yeah it seems working, thanks. But I really dont understand the use of MIN. I have problem to understand the use of HAVING...I was thinking HAVING is filtering the result after GROUP BY. Ok the count(s.*) = 1 was on data before grouping, but the MIN is totaly magic for me :)

Comment: @MychaL: since there is only one row in the group (that's what the `having` clause does), then `min()` gives you the (only) value that's available in the group.